# Aysmptotic relation

Tags: real-analysis

I have question related to asymptotic relation $\sim$. First is the following: if we know that $f(x)\sim g(x)$ as $x$ tends to $\infty$ what we can say about the asymptotic behaviour of $F(x)$ as $x$ tends to $\infty$, where $F(x)=\int\limits_{0}^{x}f(s)ds$ and $f$ is locally integrable positive function? I suspect that primitive function of $g$ must be included in it in some way but I can't see how. I tried to use $\varepsilon-\delta$ technique but I stuck. Thank you for any tips. 
**Edit:** maybe some simple examples could be helpful.
1. $f(x)\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ as $x$ tends to $\infty$. If that means $F(x)\sim \sqrt{x}$ as $x$ tends to $\infty$? 
2. $f(x)\sim \frac{1}{x^{2}}$ as $x$ tends to $\infty$. If that means $F(x)\sim \frac{1}{x}$ as $x$ tends to $\infty$?

Comment: l'hospital on $F/G$ should knock out some class of cases.

Comment: @anon we can't use de l'Hospital rule if we don't know limits of $f$ and $g$ when $x \to +\infty$.

Comment: @qoqosz $f\sim g$ means that $f/g\to1$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: For front-weighted functions can't say much, $f(x)=e^{-x}$, $g(x)=10^6$ for $0\le x\le 1$, $g(x)=e^{-x}$ for $x\gt 1$.

Comment: @anon sorry, I meant $F$ and $G$.

Comment: @qoqosz Hence "some class of cases"; like $f,g\to\infty$.

Comment: @qoqosz: Would positive, bounded away from $0$ be good enough?

Comment: Something is missing in the question: namely, a definition of $\sim$. This symbol has more than one meaning.

Comment: The suggestion in part 2. of the Edit is extremely odd. Unfortunately, the OP quit the page without leaving explanations.